# How to reference a job in the folder hierachy? (Jenkins Cloudbees Folders Plugin)

Tags: plugins, jenkins, directory, cloudbees

I use the Jenkins Copy Artifact plugin to copy artifacts from other jobs.  When this 'other job' is itself in a Folder how do I reference it?  I assume I've just not worked out the path syntax.

thanks

Glenn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the latest Copy Artifact 1.27 does not support this, but the trunk version (to be 1.28) has [various folder-related fixes](https://github.com/jenkinsci/copyartifact-plugin/pull/19): then both `/full/path/to/other/job` or `../relative/path` will work.